# How to save a string coming from a HTML response in Katalon Studio

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio, katalon

i’m here to ask you if there’s a way in Katalon Studio to store in a variable a dynamic string that is generated in the response of a rest API (POST) in HTML format. I have to use the saved string in the body of another request.
How can i do? I know it can be done with some code in script mode but don'know exactly how.
Thank You

Comment: What do you mean "dynamic string"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WS.sendRequest()` returns [`ResponseObject`](https://api-docs.katalon.com/com/kms/katalon/core/testobject/ResponseObject.html).

You can then use the built-in [`JsonSluper.parseText()`](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) on `response.getResponseBodyContent()` to get a `Map` out of the response body.

The code for that looks something like this:

```
final ResponseObject response = WS.sendRequest(yourRequestTestObject);

final String yourValue = new JsonSlurper()
  .parseText(response.getResponseBodyContent())
  .yourKey // replace with the key of the response data you're trying to get
```

Let me know if you have any questions on this, and I will try my best to help you!